# Un able to Set value to asp DropDownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using jquery-1.4.4. i am trying to set value of dropdown list using jquery way in internet explorer 6.

> $('#ddlDistricts').val(SetValueL);

if i take the count of items inside the dropdown list it is showing 3 items and it is working fine with ie7,8 and firefox4.0.

Please tell me how we select the dropdownlist item with value in ie6 using jquery.

Thanks in advance
Rajeev

Comment: Are the items in the drop-down list being added programatically client-side (i.e. with jQuery)?

Answer (score 0):

Set value as given below:

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //adding state dynamic.
    var zIdL = "1";var zDisplayMemberL = "State1";
    $("#ddlStates").append($("<option></option>").val(zIdL).html(zDisplayMemberL));
    zIdL = "2";zDisplayMemberL = "State2";
    $("#ddlStates").append($("<option></option>").val(zIdL).html(zDisplayMemberL));
    zIdL = "3";zDisplayMemberL = "State3";
    $("#ddlStates").append($("<option></option>").val(zIdL).html(zDisplayMemberL));
    //now take the state id
    var SetValueL = "2";
    //now we set the value
    $("#ddlStates").val(SetValueL);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr> 
        <td align="right"> State: </td> <td align="left"> 
        <select name="ddlStates" id="ddlStates" style="width:200px;">
        </select> </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ivapa3/2)**

Comment: Have you tried this page in internet explorer 6. This code is not working. No luck with the above code. it works fine with all other browsers except ie6.

Comment: what selection it display in ie6 if u click on the DEMO link.

Comment: When ever i try to set the value in ie6, it give a un specified error javascript error.

Comment: did u try with the given link

Comment: yes, it is showing correctly, Textbox2 is showing there. but why for me it is giving unspecified error

Comment: did u put ur JQuery code inside $(document).ready( function as i did.

Comment: i am using a seperate js class and calling the method from the js file to page on selection change of dropdownlist

Comment: In yr .js file did u put yr java-script code in $(document).ready( function?

Comment: can u post somewhat code block of js file and html markup of dropdown.

Comment: ---Html----
<tr>
<td align="right">
State:
</td>
<td align="left">
<asp:DropDownList Width="200px" ID="ddlStates" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
District:
</td>
<td align="left">
<asp:DropDownList Width="200px" ID="ddlDistricts" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
---Html---

Comment: $(dropdown).append($("<option></option>").val(zIdL).html(zDisplayMemberL));
i am takeing data from database and adding dynamically adding like the above line.

Once the state dropdown is filled, i will take the state id and pass set to the ddlstates and trigger
the change event of ddlstates and populate the ddldistrict. and i will pass the id of ddldistrict 
like this
$('#ddlDistricts').val(SetValueL);

suddenly it will give an javascript error only in ie - unspecifed error, line no 1644

i am tired of this error..........

Comment: There is no option in this forum to replay to post. only this small comment box only, sorry for the break up of one post

Comment: well... u can post HTML by editing ur question.plz see the updated answer and also see the DEMO link.try with the given code at yr end.is that working?

Comment: Thanks Sukhi for your valuable replay, let me check it out

Comment: i Resolved my issue by the solution specified in this website. http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/05/jquery-ie6-and-could-not-set-selected.html .  Thank you